# How to define steps for Scenario Outline with ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a registration form and need to test it using cucumber and ruby. 
I decided to user Scenario Outline with different values in table:

```
Scenario Outline: Log in with valid data
   Given I am on the Sign up Form
   When I provide <Email>
   And I provide Confirm <СEmail>
   And I provide <Password>
   And I provide Confirm <СPassword>
   And I click on Register button
   Then I registered to the site

Examples:
| Email                | CEmail              | Password | CPassword       |
| vip17041@yopmail.com |vip17041@yopmail.com | 123      | 123             |
| vip17042@yopmail.com |vip17042@yopmail.com |123       | 123             |
```

Now I need create steps definition. In step definition I need to put into the fields values from the table.
How could I do that? Previously I used the next method:

```
    When(/^I provide vip(\d+)@yopmail\.com$/) do |email|
         browser.text_field(:name, "Email").set("email@yopmail.com")
```

But how could I set instead of hard coded email - email from my table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to merge the capture with the email address:

```
When(/^I provide (vip\d+)@yopmail\.com$/) do |email|
     browser.text_field(:name, "Email").set("#{email}@yopmail.com")
end
```

This will concatenate the captured text ("vip" literally plus any number of numerical values with a length of one or more) with the string "@yopmail.com"

**A note on how Scenario Outline works**

Scenario Outline will grab the lines from the examples table, and simply use the columns to create individual scenarios that use the values that match the column headers in place of the placeholders.

For instance:

```
Scenario Outline: A note
 Given I am logged in as <user>
 When I go to the homepage
 Then I should see "Welcome Back, <display_name>"

Examples:
| user           | display_name |
| rick@stley.com | Rick Astley  |
| tammy1992      | Tammy Holmes |
```

Would be converted into two scenarios:

```
Scenario: A note
 Given I am logged in as rick@stley.com
 When I go to the homepage
 Then I should see "Welcome Back, Rick Astley"

Scenario: A note
 Given I am logged in as tammy1992
 When I go to the homepage
 Then I should see "Welcome Back, Tammy Holmes"
```

Which makes it no different to writing your normal scenario, the place holders that you use simply complete the step that you are writing.

**How I would write your Scenario**

Cucumber is a tool meant to bridge the conversational gap between testers, developers and management.

```
Scenario Outline: Log in with valid data
   Given I am on the Sign up Form
   When I sign up with the email "<Email>" and password "<Password>"
   Then I should be able to log in as "<Email>" with password "<Password>"

Examples:
| Email                | Password |
| vip17041@yopmail.com | 123      |
| vip17042@yopmail.com | 123      |
```

We don't necessarily have to know each individual step of the process, and the feature file shows the intent of the test.
What this seems to be looking for is whether you can log in after registering a new account, so why not write it as such?

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has used Cucumber for many years I would advise you to avoid using Scenario Outlines. Features and scenarios are for expressing intent in simple clear terms, not programming things using tables.

You can write your scenario as

```
Scenario: I should be welcomed when I sign in
  Given I am registered
  When I sign in
  Then I should be welcomed
```

Good scenarios state what behaviour they are trying to verify in their title, and then have steps that are consistent with this behaviour. They have no need to explain HOW your application implements that behaviour. Putting that information in your scenarios makes them longer, harder to implement, and much more difficult to maintain.

A side effect of such simple scenarios is that the step definitions are much simpler and easier to write. No regex's params or table parsing needed here.

You can see a simple example of this approach here (https://github.com/diabolo/cuke_up/tree/master/features),